# Something similar to Don Julio 1942

Tags: recommendations, tequila

We love this tequila but can't find it anywhere any more. Can somebody recommend something similar?

> **1942** pays homage to the year Don Julio González began his tequila-making journey. Produced in small batches and aged for a minimum of two and a half years. Bright golden amber colour; the bouquet is filled with notes of caramel, chocolate and flavours of toasty oak, vanilla and cooked agave; with a long lingering finish. - [Tequila Don Julio 1942](http://www.lcbo.com/lcbo/product/tequila-don-julio-1942/31153#.Wi25EnOvDqA)

Comment: Is tequila really that variable? I'd just get something with a similar style at a similar price point, or abandon the Don Julio and just look for a new, good tequila

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to ask your local specialty store if they know which distributor makes Tromba Tequila. The gentleman who first distilled Don Julio is the distiller and part-owner of the brand I believe, and their Anejo might be similar to 1942.

It's tough to recommend particular tequilas as we don't know where you are and tequila brands are very regional as far as U.S. availability goes.